# How to replace the edit text value in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have stored value in First screen and pass that value and set the value in Edit Text of Second screen. While i am back into first screen and change the value and pass again to second screen and set that value in edit text. Here, it shows previous value only doesn't replace that value.

```
EditText mobilenumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobilenumber);
mobilenumber.setText(mobile);
```

Above mobile is a variable and I stored the value from first screen and pass it to second screen to set that value in mobilenumber edit text.

Comment: Here second screen of showing edit text is non editable

Comment: how you are setting value..provide your code.

Comment: mobile is a variable and mobilenumber is edittext  mobilenumber.setText(mobile);

Comment: Post relevant code ?

Comment: EditText mobilenumber = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobilenumber);          mobilenumber.setText(mobile); mobile variable new value is coming i put log and checked but its not set the editext

Comment: post your code in question.

Comment: update your question and post there your code..dont post it in comment.

Comment: how are you passing the value ?

Comment: stored in SharedPreferences and put the log in second screen and checked the new value is coming to second screen or not. but its coming not replace the edit text.  Note: In XML i set the second screen edit text is non editable.

Comment: please post full code so that we do not guess answers.

Comment: first screen have one edit text and submit button. enter the edit text in first screen and click the submit button i launch the second screen and set the value of second screen edit text. first time its working fine no problem,. While i come back into first screen and enter the new text and launch the second screen in edit text previous value only showing it doesn't replaces value.

Comment: @SaravananSelvam Post both screen code

Answer (score 1):

1)if you are using activity(first screen and second screen). you can send value using intent.

```
intent.putExtra("mobile",mobile);
```

and access it in second screen using

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("mobile","defaultvalue");
```

OR

2) Make mobile as global and static variable in first activity
and in second activity(screen)

in onResume()

```
setText(firstactivity.mobile);
```

Comment: first screen and second screen both are fragment.

Comment: Static variables are fun because they're cleared to `null` on process death

Comment: make your global variable in activity and in second screen overload onResume method and access it. as EpicPandaForce said if you are using to many static variable at some point any variable cleared to null

Comment: in second fragment field set the static EditText mobilenumber and set the value from first fragment. like second fragment.mobilenumber.setText(). it gave NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

Answer (score 0):

As you said both the screen are fragment you can share a global variable in activity(if both fragment part of same activity) or

> can communicate via passing value in bundle would be safest and
>   reliable way

Comment: how can i set the value in fragment?

Comment: If you are achieving this via global variable, that's quite simple. You can read and update that variable.

Comment: mobilenumber.setText(Firscreen.mobile);

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Bundle`

From your first activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
  super.onCreate(b);
  String number = "" + R.id.IDInYourFirstActivity;
  b.putString("mobilenumber", number);
}
```

in your next activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bd){
  super.onCreate(bd);
  String mobileNo = bd.getString("mobilenumber");

  EditText mobilenumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobilenumber);
  mobilenumber.setText(mobileNo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable in second screen. Then in first screen when you change the value then

```
Second.mobile=your value.
```

It will change the value accordingly.

Comment: in second fragment field set the static EditText mobilenumber and set the value from first fragment. like second fragment.mobilenumber.setText(). it gave NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION